# kde plasma isn't working nicely in parrot os as it works in ubuntu

Tags: linux, debian, kde, kde-plasma-5, parrot-os

Kde plasma seems to be not working correctly in parrot os as it works in ubuntu. I did apt install kde-full to insure that none of the packages that kde requires are missing even thought it does not work fine.

1. The emoji font is installed, like noto color emoji etc, almost all apps display emoji correctly but kde. all kde apps like, kate, dolphin etc even desktop does not display the emoji. any file in the desktop that contains emoji in the filename, the filename’s emoji is broken.
2. Desktop effects not working. settings > workspace behaviour > desktop effects, none of the settings applied here works, nothing at all.
3. The kde plasma version is just 5.20.5 whereas the latest version is 5.24.4. Why don’t it installs the latest version…?

To make sure this isn’t kde plasma’s problem I installed Kubuntu and checked but everything was fine, such problems were not occurred. This problem occurs only in the parrot os.

So, how do I install kde plasma correctly to make it work in parrot os like it works in ubuntu and solve the above mentioned all three problems. And also, how do I install the latest version of kde…?

```
parrot version: 5.0 kernel version: 5.16.012parrot1-amd64
```

**Following are some screenshots**

[This is how the filename appears in dolphin and in the laptop's desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r35bq.png)

[This is how the emojis appear in the kde plasma's apps like text editor kate, kwrite etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ4Jl.png)

[This is how the emojis appear in non kde apps like text editor pluma,  file explorer caja, firefox, chrome, brave etc (it is showing correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn5xS.png)

And also non of the desktop effects like window animation, transparency etc applied from desktop settings does not work as mentioned in problem 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry nobody has answered your question since you've posted it.  Actually, i'm surprised it wasn't removed considering its a statement and not a question, but I gotchu regardless since the snooty seasoned linux users seemed to have held their noses high in the air past it;

***LONG STORY SHORT: IF THE DEVS OF AN OS STOP OFFICIALLY SUPPORTING SOMETHING AND YOU LIKE IT, STAY AT THE CURRENT VERSION. IF NOT, YOU WILL EVENTUALLY RUN INTO FILE CONFIG ISSUES AND BE MAD AT NOBODY BUT YOURSELF.***

This is not a surprise that the KDE desktop environment no longer plays well with Parrot OS's debian based flavor.

It is not asurprise, because (forgive me for not knowing exact versions here, my memory is shot, im burnt af) somewhere around Parrot OS version 4.6.* to version 4.11(?), the dev's stopped supporting the KDE desktop environment entirely.

Why?

I believe they cited a specific bug, something to do with the home button, or panel, you get the point.

Seems to be rather trivial to not work out a solution to some buggy finacking considering how well Parrot ran on KDE. lol actually, no, it didnt run all that well over it... but that damn kwin_x11 window manager was just so fxcking fire.

I will stay upset over this for as many years as it takes to come back. Parrot OS - security edition - of KDE was boss af.

I've since re-earthed an old SDD with my sloppy installs of other DE's on top of, in front of and behind, before I had known any better, and came back to a non booting, debacle of folders and files as if Linus T. was trying to tell me to go back to Windows 11. Sike, i've moved onto
Garuda OS w BlackArch repos sideloaded, at least it takes KDE no problem.

After days of fumbling around with my grubenv (had the wrong set boot params like a dumbo), I got her back and booting right into sddm. All seemed well back on version 4.6 or so. Forgetting about the fact that Parrot dev's no longer chose to support KDE or vice versa idk, I update && upgrade'd with it taking me past parrots seemingly lts version that is currently being boasted on their site, and jumped into mvlinuz-parrot-6.0.*-1parrot-3t-amd64.

Dontcha know, desktop panels, the env, completely ch-chopped and sk-skrewed.

***LONG STORY SHORT: IF THE DEVS OF AN OS STOP OFFICIALLY SUPPORTING SOMETHING AND YOU LIKE IT, STAY AT THE CURRENT VERSION. IF NOT, YOU WILL EVENTUALLY RUN INTO FILE CONFIG ISSUES AND BE MAD AT NOBODY BUT YOURSELF. I'll put this at the top as well in case nobody cares to hear my bs :)***

There, I think that sums it up. peace breh

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160670)